# doctrine orm manytoone multi-column join strange error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm "enhancing" a legacy datamodel with referential integrity using doctrine ORM inside Symfony.

I have this schema yml definition

```
AppBundle\Entity\QualityDataItems:
    type: entity
    table: quality_data_items
    id:
        rfi_id:
            type: integer
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
        rfi_type:
            type: string
            length: 10
            id: true
    manyToOne:
        RfiPeople:
            targetEntity: QualityDataItemsPeople
            joinColumn:
                rfi_type:
                    referencedColumnName: rfi_type_id
                rfi_id:
                    referencedColumnName: rfi_id
    fields:
        issue_text:
            type: text
            nullable: true
            length: 65535
        response_text:
            type: text
            nullable: true
            length: 65535
        resolution_text:
            type: text
            nullable: true
            length: 65535
        add_to_report:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            options:
                unsigned: false
                default: '0'
        add_to_report_date:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
        issue_cause:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
        issue_type:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
        issue_sub_type:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
        linked_to_id:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
        status_id:
            type: integer
            nullable: true

AppBundle\Entity\QualityDataItemsPeople:
    type: entity
    table: quality_data_items_people
    id:
        rfi_ppl_idx:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    manyToOne:
        RfiJob:
            targetEntity: RfiJob
            joinColumn:
                name: rfi_id
                referencedColumnName: rfi_id
        RfiType:
            targetEntity: RfiType
            joinColumn:
                name: rfi_type
                referencedColumnName: rfi_type_id
    fields:
        rfi_id:
            type: integer
        rfi_type:
            type: string
            length: 10
        user_id:
            type: integer
```

when I run

```
bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I get:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] Column name 'id' referenced for relation from AppBundle\Entity\QualityDataItems towards AppBundle\Entity\QualityDataItemsPeople does not exist.
```

There is no column named id in these tables. I also deleted the Entity classes to be sure there is nothing in there

Comment: What kind of relation are you tying to create? (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: It's many to one with both tables having composite keys, the foreign key has more fields

Comment: Uni or bi directional?

Comment: Unidirectional at this point, but can be either

Answer (score 0):

Either it's not documented or supported, but could you give this a try?

```
manyToOne:
    RfiPeople:
        targetEntity: QualityDataItemsPeople
        joinColumns:
          - joinColumn:
                name:                 rfi_type_id
                referencedColumnName: rfi_type_id
          - joinColumn:
                name:                 rfi_id
                referencedColumnName: rfi_id
```

Comment: As a last attempt you could make an issue on the github of doctrine.